# Does Kafka's producer.flush() verify that all the data is sent to topic?

Tags: python, validation, apache-kafka

I'm sending about 12 million rows of data to Kafka topic, via Pythonic KafkaProducer on a daily basis.

The data needs to be JSON formatted, and each row as a 1 entry,
and does a `producer.flush()` every 1 million rows.

The code is provided below:

```
import json
count = 0
for key in json_df:
    x = json.dumps(key, default=str).encode('utf-8')
    producer.send('SOME_TOPIC_NAME', value=x)
    count+=1
    if (count % 1000000 == 0):
        producer.flush()
producer.flush()
```

But today I have faced a problem that 250~ rows were missing from the topic, and my question is: does the execution of `producer.flush()` more often guarantees that no data is missing?

I also have `linger_ms = 500` in KafkaProducer object, does decreasing the frequency of linger makes sure that all the data is sent to topic?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the flush is the problem. There is nothing in your code that checks if the program itself dies with less than 1M records. When you restart the producers, the count restarts a zero, and you lose all intermediate batched records.

To answer the question - yes, flush is a blocking call that empties the data that is available in the batch... Keep in mind that Kafka does have a `batch.size` upper limit (in bytes).

If you already had a [JSON-lines](https://jsonlines.org/) formatted file, you could just do

```
kafka-console-producer ... < file.jsonl
```